# Search for an object in the specified categories. HQL / MYSQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

There is a product table that has a ManyToMany link to Categories.
[image]

My goal is to select the top 5 most suitable products for the given categories.

Now I have implemented such a query, but it is not very effective, because at first it finds a match by the number of categories, and by the first match with the category name.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN p.categories c WHERE c.name IN (:categories) ORDER BY SIZE(p.categories) DESC")
    List<Product> findByCategories_NameInOrderByCount(@Param("categories") Collection<String> categories);
```

How can I improve my query so that it will be the first to return products with the largest number of categories matching the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is wrong, you should use something similar to this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p.categories c WHERE c.name IN (:categories)) > 0 ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p.categories c WHERE c.name IN (:categories)) DESC")
List<Product> findByCategories_NameInOrderByCount(@Param("categories") 
Collection<String> categories);
```

Anyway, this will probably not perform very well either because the database will have to join and sort the three tables. To avoid this, one normally uses an inverted or multi-valued index as MySQL calls it (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued). Drop the product_has_category and category tables and instead introduce a JSON column "details" in the product table.

You can then create an index:

```
CREAT INDEX categories ON product( (CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(categories, '$[*]') AS VARCHAR(80) ARRAY)) )
```

And query it like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE FUNCTION('JSON_OVERLAPS', FUNCTION('JSON_EXTRACT', p.categories, '$[*]'), :categories) = 1 ORDER BY FUNCTION('COUNT_MATCHES', p.categories, :categories) DESC")
List<Product> findByCategories_NameInOrderByCount(@Param("categories") 
String categories);
```

But you need to add a function to your database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION COUNT_MATCHES (categories JSON, searchCategories JSON)
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
   RETURN (
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM JSON_TABLE(categories, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
       name VARCHAR(80) PATH '$' ERROR ON ERROR)
     ) c
     JOIN JSON_TABLE(searchCategories, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
       name VARCHAR(80) PATH '$' ERROR ON ERROR )
     ) s ON c.name = s.name
   );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I suffered for a long time.